# Парсинг людей, которым понравилось место facebook

Tags: facebook-api

Как получить людей, которым понравилось место (place) в facebook.
Вот пример места: https://www.facebook.com/places/Cem-mozno-zanatsa-v-Oslo/110848678937314/ 
Вот люди, которым понравилось место: https://www.facebook.com/search/110848678937314/likers

Можно ли с помощью facebook api спарсить этих людей?

Comment: А что у нас на выходе обычно после пирсинга человека?

Comment: Всмысле? Мне не одного человека спарсить нужно, а список людей, лайкнувших место.

Comment: Вы так и не поняли, что я намекаю вам на то, что вопрос сформулирован не корректно, не понятно что вы хотите получить.

Comment: @stranger-in-the-q Список людей с этой страницы [ссылка](https://www.facebook.com/search/110848678937314/likers) c помощью api facebook.